# Задача, с использованием оператора цикла FOR

Tags: vba, for

помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, используя оператор цикла FOR (я новичок, почти толком не разбираюсь, можете написать как можно простым кодом): s = ((–1)^1 · 5^1 / 1) + ((–1)^2 · 5^2 /2!) + ... + (–1)^6 · 5^6 /6!

Comment: Приложите ваши попытки. Покажите что не получается. Мы не будем решать за вас.

Comment: Много имён у автора. А всё равно не в коня корм...

Answer (score 2):

что-то сегодня практически одинаковые вопросы про VBA пошли

это задача в которой не надо считать факториал для каждого числа

1. вводите переменную, в которую будете накапливать сумму и присваиваете ее 0
2. вводите переменную, в которую будете накапливать `(-1)^i * 5^i`
3. вводите переменную, в которую будете накапливать факториал и присваиваете его 1
4. проходите в цикле от 1 до 6
5. вычисляете факториал для текущего числа умножением текущего числа на факториал предыдущего числа
6. увеличиваете сумму на значение вычисленного факториала

т.е. ваш алгоритм такой:

```
итог = 0
степень = 1
факториал = 1

цикл от 1 до 6
    степень = степень * (-5)
    факториал = факториал * значение цикла
    итог = итог + степень / факториал

вывод результата
```

по идее `степень` и `факториал` можно совместить

```
итог = 0
факториал = 1

цикл от 1 до 6
    факториал = факториал * (-5) / значение цикла
    итог = итог + факториал

вывод результата
```